# How to print the current value of the list in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

Can anybody helps me to figure out a way to print the current value of the list, I have to loop on List tag and print his current children.

**Input xml:**

```
<Lists>
 <List>
    <ChildrenList>
   <ChildName> John </ChildName>
    </ChildrenList>
 </List>
 <List>
   <ChildrenList>
   <ChildName> Jo </ChildName>
   <ChildName> Smith </ChildName>
    </ChildrenList>

 </List>
</Lists>
```

**Desired output**

```
<Children> 
  <ChildrenList1>
    <ChildName> John </ChildName>
 </ChildrenList1>
</Children>

<Children> 
  <ChildrenList1>
   <ChildName> Jo </ChildName>
   <ChildName> Smith </ChildName>
 </ChildrenList1>
</Children>
```

**My XSLT**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Children> 
        <ChildrenList1>
            <xsl:for-each select="Lists/List/ChildrenList">
                <ChildName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ChildName"/>
                </ChildName>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ChildrenList1>
    </Children> 
</xsl:template>
```

unfortunately, I got the following

```
<Children>
<ChildrenList1>
        <ChildName> John </ChildName>
        <ChildName> Jo </ChildName>
</ChildrenList1>
</Children>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code: it will achive by apply templates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="List">
        <Children>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Children>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ChildrenList">
        <ChildrenList1>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ChildrenList1>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or if you really want to achive it by your way then you need one more nesting for-each like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Children>
            <xsl:for-each select="Lists/List/ChildrenList">
                <ChildrenList1>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ChildName">
                        <ChildName>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </ChildName>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ChildrenList1>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Children>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Updated As desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Childrens>
            <xsl:for-each select="Lists/List">
                <Children>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ChildrenList">
                        <ChildrenList1>
                            <xsl:for-each select="ChildName">
                                <ChildName>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </ChildName>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </ChildrenList1>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Children>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Childrens>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried the second xsl but it didn't give the desired output  . it combined all children in single tag. can you help me to reach it to the desired.

Comment: @newibeK its my foult to not see proper required output, now answer updated you can see last one, Hope it will give your desire output. But the best way to go with template for each which was suggest as first if you dont have specific reason to use for-each. it will take more processing time.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the expected output easily by doing:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Lists">
    <xsl:for-each select="List/ChildrenList">
        <Children> 
            <ChildrenList1>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ChildName"/>
            </ChildrenList1>
        </Children>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the result is an XML fragment. To produce a well-formed XML document, you must add a root element, for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Lists">
    <Root>
        <xsl:for-each select="List/ChildrenList">
            <Children> 
                <ChildrenList1>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="ChildName"/>
                </ChildrenList1>
            </Children>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```